# Atom - atom ide is changing code after save

Tags: atom-editor

is there any reason of why my atom is destroying my code after I save my file.
My code looks something like this (after save):[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry for having to ask the obvious question: What did it look like before? Can you outline (or mark in the screenshot) what has changed in the code?

Comment: Yo can see in the line 13, but if we could see through the whole code, we'll see a lot of changed code similar to line 13.

Comment: Same thing happening to me. Very annoying. Please update if you have found a solution. I'm about to switch back to submlime.

Comment: I basically do the following when the code is destroyed (after save it): 1. Ctrl Z (to undo changes) 2. Copy the whole code 3. Save the file (the code will be destroyed) 4. Paste the code again replacing the desroyed one. So you likely won't have any problems anymore.